# как ввести getBooleanExtra if else? чтобы вышло так чтобы на 3-ей странице вышло что мы вошли из логина или с регистрации

Tags: android, kotlin

это первое активити

```
    val registr =findViewById<Button>(R.id.registr)

    registr.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(applicationContext,Registration::class.java )

        startActivity(intent)



    }




    val login = findViewById<Button>(R.id.log)
    val inputName = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.inputName)
    val pass = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.pass)

    login.setOnClickListener {
        val text = inputName.text.toString()


        val intent = Intent(applicationContext,ThirdActivity::class.java)

        intent.putExtra("fromlogin",text)




        startActivity(intent)

    }

}
```

это второе активити

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setContentView(R.layout.regist)



    val five = findViewById<Button>(R.id.five)

    val three = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.three)
    val  four = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.four)
    five.setOnClickListener {

        val text = three.text.toString()

        val intent = Intent(applicationContext,ThirdActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("fromlogin",text)

        startActivity(intent)
    }


}
```

это третье активити

```
class ThirdActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_third)



    val data = intent.getStringExtra("fromlogin")
    val textview= findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)
    textView.text=data


    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, data, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()




















}
```

}

[image: чтобы вниз, под сворачиванием окна ,вышло что с первого активити вошла на 3 активити и на 3 активити вышло что я вошел на из первого активити или со второго все спасибо !]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас в коде предыдущего вопроса передавалось булево значение - так и делайте.

В активности с логином:

```
intent.putExtra("fromlogin", true)
```

В активности с регистрацией:

```
intent.putExtra("fromlogin", false)
```

В третьей:

```
if (intent.getBooleanExtra("fromlogin", false)) {
    // your code
} else {
   // your code
}
```

Comment: woesss спасибо большое!

Comment: woesss извини, у меня что то пустой экран выходит

Comment: А ты в курсе что через интент можно передавать несколько параметров? Только ключи нужно использовать разные. `intent.putExtra("fromlogin", false)` ... `intent.putExtra("text", text)` ... `intent.putExtra("bla-bla", "что хочу, то и передаю")`. А в другой активности получать их по тем же ключам (ключ - это строка, которую мы передаём первым аргументом в `putExtra()` и `getXXExtra()`).

Comment: если я в первом активити и во втором ставлю true и false вместо texta, наверно text отвечает за появление на экране

Comment: Так в чём проблема? В одной активности добавь текст: `intent.putExtra("text", text)`, в другой забери: `val data = intent.getStringExtra("text")`

Comment: woesss, спасибо тебе большое теперь вышло ! большое спасибо !!!!!!

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7025/11515